# How to remove unallocated index from an array when appending using for loop

Tags: c

```
int array[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                array[i] = i;
            }
            
        }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
}
```

I've been trying to figure out assigning for loop values to a array and print them out accordingly. The second j for loop is just there to simualte the actual project I'm working on and I've created a separate c file for this particular extraction to test it out. As far as I know the array should be printing `{0,3,6}`but it seems to be printing `{0, 1, 71341984, 3, 71341680, 1, 6, 1, 4185744}`. Is there any way to avoid these unassigned indexes?

Comment: I ran this and it just prints `0 0 0 3 0 0 6 0 0`. Please provide a more complete snippet of code, or write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DanteCulaciati that is the entire code i have on my separate c file.

Comment: Except 0, 1, 3 and 6 the big numbers keeps on changing after each excution

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I'm not questioning whether that is your entire code, I'm saying that in order for us to more easily solve your problem you should provide a minimal reproducible example or explain your code structure in a more complete way.

Comment: If your array is a properly initialized array of pointers to integers then you can easily ignore unassigned elements when printing them out.

Comment: Run it with a debugger, pay attention to the uninitialized values that are there on start, and how they change as your program runs. It will be clear to you when you do that.

Comment: Why do you declare an array with size 10 if you only intend to use 9 items?

Answer (score 3):

Local variables that have not been initialized have **indeterminate** values.  This basically means that if you attempt to read them, their contents could be any value and (because the array elements never had their address taken) could even change on subsequent reads.

You should initially set all values of the array to some known sentinel value that is known to be invalid and use that value to see if a given array element is valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the program should only print "0 3 6".  However, your last `for` loop prints out the value at every single index and there are nine indices.

If you want to avoid printing the unassigned values, then you need to tell your program that.  You're only assigning a value to `array[i]` when `i%3 == 0`.  Therefore, that condition needs to be in your loop:

```c
for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if ( i%3 == 0 ) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
}
```